# Can we construct a random variable without a density function? (except for the finite discrete R.V.)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

A random variable is defined by it distribution function. The density function is the derivative of the distribution function. Thus the density function exisst iff the distribution function is absolutely continuous. However, can we construct a distribution function without a density function, except for the finite discrete random variable(i.e. the distribution function is a step function)?

I think the hardness is that the distribution function is non-decreasing and upper-bounded by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Masacroso's answer, there are examples of continuous random variables that do not have densities. The standard construction involves the *Cantor function*.

If you're not familiar with the Cantor set, this set is constructed via the following iteration:

- Start with $C_0 = [0,1]$.
- To get $C_{k+1}$ take every interval in $C_k$ and remove an open interval around the middle third. Thus, $C_1 = [0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]$, $C_2 = [0,1/9]\cup[2/9,1/3]\cup[2/3,7/9]\cup[8/9,1]$ etc.
- $C = \bigcap_{k=0}^\infty C_k$.

It turns out that $C$ is an uncountably infinite set, but it has Lebesgue measure 0. We can characterize $C$ as the set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansion in base 3 does not have any 1's. Thus, $1/3 = 0.1_3 = 0.0\overline{222}_3$ and $8/27 = 0.022_3$ are in the Cantor set, but $5/9 = 0.12_3$ is not.

So now we can define the *Cantor function*. First, consider the function $g:C \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined in the following manner. To compute $g(x)$,

- Write out $x$ in base 3 decimal form.
- Replace all 2s with 1s.
- Switch to binary.

For example, $g(1/3) = g(0.0\overline{222}_3) = 0.0\overline{111}_2 = 0.1_2 = 1/2$. Or $g(8/27) = g(0.022_3) = 0.011_2 = 3/8$. $g$ is a strictly increasing, surjective function.

Define $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ in the following way. If $x \in C$, then $f(x) = g(x)$. Otherwise, $f(x) = \max_{y< x, y \in C} g(y)$.

$f$ is a continuous, increasing, surjective function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Furthermore, since $f$ is constant outside the Cantor set, the derivative of $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere (recall that the Cantor set has Lebesgue measure $0$). But, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Therefore, the random variable with cumulative distribution function $f$ is a continuous random variable without a density.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is a perfect example I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Of course we can, there are the mixed distributions.

In short: any increasing and right continuous function $F$ with $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=1$ defines a probability distribution on $\Bbb R$. When $F$ is differentiable then the random variable represented by $F$ have a density. If $F$ is a step function then it represent a discrete random variable. All the other cases are mixed cases.

Moreover: if $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is a random variable then $X$ and the probability measure $P$ in $\Omega$ induces a probability measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R$. Then the distribution of $X$ is the function $F$ such that $\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$, and it can be shown that $F$ have the properties above described.

Comment: Thanks very much, I get your point. The reason I ask this question is that I want to construct a bounded R.V. (for example valued in [a,b]) that do not have a expectation, and if the density function exist or in the finite discrete case, the expectation exist. So is that possible to construct a R.V. whose expectation do not exist?

Comment: Any bounded R.V. always has a well-defined expectation.

Comment: A random variable is by definition a measurable function from the sample space to some state space. Because of this, we can always describe the distribution of a random variable using a measure on the state space (called the law of the random variable), even when no density exists. Suppose a random variable $X$ has law $\mu$. For any measurable function $f$,

$$E[f(X)] = \int f(x)d\mu(x).$$

The only way for the expectation not to exist is if $f(x)$ is not Lebesgue-integrable with respect to $\mu$. This cannot happen when $f$ is bounded on the support of $X$.

Comment: Or, you can define a (nonnegative) random variable $X\geq 0$ to have expectation $E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P[X>t]dt$. Even if $X$ has no density, it must have a CDF $P[X\leq x]$ and hence $P[X>t]$ exists and is non-increasing in $x$. You can define $E[X]$ for a general (possibly negative) random variable by $E[X] = E[X^+]-E[X^-]$ whenever the right-hand-side avoids the undefined case of $\infty -\infty$ (in which case $E[X]$ does not exist). If $X$ is bounded then $E[X^+]$ and $E[X^-]$ are both finite so the expectation always exists.